# how to wirte test for private function?

Tags: scala

This is my private function, it will return three types, success error or fault, and I want to test this private function.

```
 class GrpcAuthClientInterceptor{
private def getToken(clientAuth: ClientAuthentication, format: String, provider: String, scopes: String): TokenCommandResult = {
        val request = makeTokenRequest(provider, format, scopes, this.audience.asInstanceOf[String], clientAuth)
        val result = new TokenCommand(request).execute()
        result match {
            case success: TokenCommandResult.Success => printAndSaveToken(format, success.getResponse.getOIDCTokens.getAccessToken.getValue)
            case error: TokenCommandResult.Error => printError(format, error.getError.getErrorObject.getDescription)
            case fault: TokenCommandResult.Fault => printError(format, fault.getException.getMessage)
        }
        result
    }
}
```

This is how I test it, I tried to use reflection to do that, but I got error, how can I fix that?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Interceptor.GrpcAuthClientInterceptorTest$$anon$1.getToken(com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.auth.ClientAuthentication, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

```
class GrpcAuthClientInterceptorTest {
    private var serverInterceptor = null
    private val grpcAuthClientInterceptor = new GrpcAuthClientInterceptor {
        override var audience: Nothing = _
    }
    private var clientId = ""
    private var provider = ""
    private var clientSecret = "
    private var scope = null
    private var baseUrl = null
    private var format = "jwt-application"


    test("test") {

        val getToken = this.grpcAuthClientInterceptor.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("getToken", classOf[ClientAuthentication], classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[String]) //got error at this line
        val clientSecretBasic = new ClientSecretBasic(new ClientID(clientId), new Secret(clientSecret))
        val token = getToken.invoke(grpcAuthClientInterceptor, clientSecretBasic, format, provider, null)

        assertTrue(token.isInstanceOf[TokenCommandResult.Success])
    }
}
```

```
val theFunction = PrivateMethod[TokenCommandResult]('getToken)
val result = grpcAuthClientInterceptor invokePrivate theFunction()
```

Comment: The quick question is you can't, you either need reflection, or you test it by testing a public method, or you make the method `private[somePackage]` so that the test can access it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know too much about reflection, maybe is because is an anonymous class? Or maybe there is some magic involved in the original class? I would try to start small with a plain class and see if it works and then start adding more things to make it equal to the real class to see where it breaks. - You may also want to open a different question just focused in the reflection bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `theFunction()` in the final line of your question you need to pass it the necessary parameters. It would look something like:

```
val result = grpcAuthClientInterceptor invokePrivate theFunction(clientSecretBasic, format, provider, scopes)
```